# making OAuth refresh token call to generate a new access token

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0

I would appreciate some advice around managing the point in my web app (browser based) where I need to send my refresh token to generate a new access token, in OAuth (Resource Owner Flow)

Currently I have it so that when I receive a 401 network error, I call a 'refreshToken' method which creates the request with the request token that is needed to obtain a new access token (and new refresh token) - this works fine and I receive the new tokens and the app carries on.

However, the request which caused the 401 to happen is lost, and that might be important.

After googling around I have seem some people use a timeout which is shorter than the token life to pre-emptively refresh the token, or I have also seen examples where failed api calls are repeated. This latter example, repeating api calls that fail, seems more robust but also introduces some complexity.

What advice can developers who have developed code like this give me on what is the best strategy or if there is another way I have not discovered.

Many Thanks

James

Comment: here's a example of queueing failed requests for angular:
https://jeremymarc.github.io/2014/08/14/oauth2-with-angular-the-right-way

Answer (score 0):

After some googling looks like the best thing is to use some variation on this theme:

[http-request-queue](https://github.com/johnathanhowell/http-request-queue)

for some asynch/await goodness.